# Bad substitution when using bash

Tags: bash, netcat

This is my code

```sh
#!/bin/bash

PING_STATUS="${netcat -vz mc.bella.wtf 25565}"
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"embeds": [{"title": "Server Status:","color": 16027903,"description": "'"$PING_STATUS"'"}]}' "$WEBHOOK"
```

I get this when running it

```sh
mc@ubuntu:~$ serverping
./server/server/ping: line 3: ${netcat -vz mc.bella.wtf 25565}: bad substitution
```

I already tried escaping the `-` and `.` to be sure

**EDIT**: solved

I had to use () instead of {}

Comment: Did you mean `$(...)` instead of `${...}`? `${...}` is for variable substitution, `$(...)` is for running commands and substituting their output.

Comment: That fixes the issue, but now when it's run the output is just nothing to bash?

Comment: `netcat`'s verbose output (`-v`) goes to stderr, so you need to tack on `2>&1` to capture it.

Comment: That worked, thank you!